# Comparing model performance to mean value performance

Tags: python

I wanted to predict the ages of Titanic passengers, but I noticed that people often just fill missing age values with the mean age. I wanted to compare my model's performance with the simple mean value approach. My questions are:

1. Is the R-squared metric a good indicator to determine if my model
   performs better than the average age value?
2. If I want to calculate the mean absolute error for the average age value
   , should I treat it like a model? Should I calculate the
   mean value using the training data and then calculate its MAE score
   with the testing data, or should I use the whole dataset to
   calculate the mean?
3. How should I implement point nr.2 in python? Create list of mean values like `[age_target_data.mean() for _ in age_target_list]` and insert it to scikit-learn `mean_absolute_error(age_target_list,age_mean_list)`

Answer (score 0):

1.R squared is certainly one valid way to look at how different attributes contribute to the variance of the output. I used the correlation matrix, but other techniques are viable.

```
corr_matrix = train_set.corr()
corr_matrix["Survived"].sort_values(ascending=False)`
```

2. You could calculate the mean with training data only and then impute any missing values in the test data at inference time. Or you could create a first model only for finding the age of the passengers, doing a regression on all the other variables to make a prediction of the passengers age, and then use the output of that model as input to a second model to determine survival. A compromise would be something in between, like using the mean or median of some of the inputs to compute a best guess for the age.
3. Something like the following:

   ```
   train_set['Age'] = train_set['Age'].fillna(train_set.groupby(["Sex","Pclass"])['Age'].transform('median'))
   test_set['Age'] = test_set['Age'].fillna(train_set.groupby(["Sex","Pclass"])['Age'].transform('median'))
   ```